# Parameter #2 $string of function explode expects string, SimpleXMLElement|null given

Tags: php, unit-testing, testing, phpstan

I've tried looking at a lot of solutions and still can't seem to find a fix for my issue. I keep getting the following error:

```
Parameter #2 $string of function explode expects string, SimpleXMLElement|null given.
```

I've never had this issue before and it's only started appearing after updating Statamic to the latest version. This is my code within the GenerateFavicons.php:

```
private function createThumbnail(
    string $import,
    string $export,
    int $width,
    int $height,
    string $background,
    ?int $border
): void {
$svg = file_get_contents($import);
    if (!$svg) {
        return;
    }
    $svgObj = simplexml_load_string($svg);

    if (!$svgObj) {
        return;
    }

    $viewBox = explode(' ', $svgObj['viewBox']);
    $viewBoxWidth = intval($viewBox[2]);
    $viewBoxHeight = intval($viewBox[3]);
```

The error is showing for the following line of code:

```
$viewBox = explode(' ', $svgObj['viewBox']);
```

From what I've seen, a lot of people have been saying you shouldn't explode an array. I'm not quite sure where to go from here.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why would you `explode an array`? It's already broken into pieces. Also, your error is saying that `$svgObj['viewBox']` is not a string. Did try `var_dump($svgObj['viewBox'])` to see what `$svgObj['viewBox']` is?

Comment: `$svgObj['something']` is itself a `SimpleXMLElement` (or could be `null`) which is what the warning is about. The code itself will probably work because of [type juggling](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php) but it's better to explicitly cast it using e.g. `explode(' ', strval($svgObj['viewBox']))`. Seeing how the value could be null it's probably good to check that as well

Comment: @apokryfos, that got rid of the error. Thank you